# How to restrict user from switching from tablet mode () in retargeting Windows 8.1 to Windows 10?

Tags: windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I have created an app in Windows 8.1 and running it on Windows 10 tablet, but I want to run the app in landscape mode only.

How can I restrict the user from switching to tablet mode from the action center?

Answer (score 0):

> but i want to run app in landscape mode only

You can add `InitialRotationPreference` in your package manifest:

```
 <InitialRotationPreference>
    <Rotation Preference="landscape"/>
</InitialRotationPreference>
```

This will keep your app displaying in landscape and will not change the orientation when device is held in Portrait or Portraitflipped.

Foe more details, see [InitialRotationPreference](http://InitialRotationPreference).

> need to restrict user to switch tablet mode from action center.

Check the last FAQ in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/commercialize/design/device-experiences/continuum?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#frequently-ask-questions-faq):

***screen rotation is not necessarily related to tablet mode. Screen rotation is tied to your current device configuration which may or may not map to whether the device is in “tablet mode”***.

**Updated**:

The [ConvertibleSlateModePromptPreference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/commercialize/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-shell-convertibleslatemodepromptpreference) is for OEMs. There does not exist a WinRT API to realize this currently.

Comment: but i am only running my window 8.1 app on window 10 tablet..  can i use ConvertibleSlateModePromptPreference  in window 8.1? so that it can work on window 10 tablet.